# Android remote debugger module

Tags: android, debugging, titanium, appcelerator

Anyone know Android remote debugger, which is a module, that is compiled together into an app. When an error occur on the app that installed on users device, this module will send debug info back to a web service.

Also, is it possible to include this module into Appcelerator Titanium -based app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Apphance.com](http://www.apphance.com/) , there's a free version of it, so you can test this tool.

Comment: exactly what i'm looking for, but free version only allow 3 devices..T_T